# ¿Como mostrar una alerta a una etiqueta <ul> que este deshabilitada, jquery?

Tags: jquery

Al tener la etiqueta deshabilitada de la siguiente forma:

```
<ul class="lista_productos_elegir3" style="max-height: 55vh; overflow: scroll;" disabled="disabled"></ul>
```

Entonces quiero mostrar una alerta cuando le den click a la etiqueta  deshabilitada, indicandoles porque motivo esta deshabilitada.

Pero ni accede a la funciona.

```
$$('.lista_productos_elegir3').on('click',function(e){
  console.log("SELECCIONANDO UL");
});
```

Existira alguna forma para controlar esto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La propiedad disabled cambia el cursor, el cual no permite lanzar eventos clicks.
Te recomiendo crear una clase disabled y dale el estilo.

```js
$('input').click(function (event) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
            alert('CLICKEADO, PERO DESHABILITADO!!');
        } else {
            alert('No deshabilitado. =)');
        }
    });
```

```css
.disabled
{
    background-color: #DDD;
    color: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="disabled" value="deshabilitado click" />

<input type="button" value="click habilitado!" />
```

Answer (score 1):

**Una lista `<ul>`no puede tener un atributo `disabled`**. Puedes utilizar CSS para crear un efecto parecido a `disabled` si le das `pointer-events:none;` y `opacity:.5;`

El atributo `disabled` puede ser utilizado con los siguientes elementos: `<button>
<fieldset> <input> <optgroup> <option> <select> <textarea>`

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto:

```
$('.lista_productos_elegir3').on('click',function(e){
  alert('Hola mundo');
});
```

Nota: También puedes personalizar una alerta [aquí](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/)